# Raid6 mdadm reshape operation interrupted - now cannot mount or examine

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, raid6

**Edit:** Once the reshape finished the drive became fully accessible again.

I had a power failure while a raid6 array was being reshaped, and now certain operations cannot be run against it, including mounting or `mdadm --examine`.

To add to my woes, one of the drives failed a smart test and has read errors.

The reshape has resumed, but I fear there is some corruption that won't get repaired if/when it completes.

Here's the output of `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : active raid6 sdg1[2] sdf1[1] sde1[0] sdd1[5] sdb1[3](S) sda[7] sdc[6]
      78126764032 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [7/6] [UUU_UUU]
      [==>..................]  reshape = 14.4% (2815896576/19531691008) finish=3158.8min speed=88196K/sec
      bitmap: 0/146 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

And the output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md127`

```
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Jan  4 19:40:02 2023
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 78126764032 (72.76 TiB 80.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 19531691008 (18.19 TiB 20.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 7
     Total Devices : 7
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Jan 30 15:22:19 2023
             State : clean, degraded, reshaping 
    Active Devices : 6
   Working Devices : 7
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Reshape Status : 14% complete
     Delta Devices : 1, (6->7)

              Name : vault:data  (local to host vault)
              UUID : 24ae0875:70f1f195:6e1fdbc3:6bb65abb
            Events : 342749

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       65        0      active sync   /dev/sde1
       1       8       81        1      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       2       8       97        2      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       -       0        0        3      removed
       6       8       32        4      active sync   /dev/sdc
       5       8       49        5      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       7       8        0        6      active sync   /dev/sda

       3       8       17        -      spare   /dev/sdb1
```

And the output of `strace -f mount /dev/md127 /data`

```
execve("/usr/bin/mount", ["mount", "/dev/md127", "/data"], 0x7ffc4559e6c8 /* 15 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55996f246000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fff67a72f60) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4df4766000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=42399, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 42399, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df475b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libmount.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=292552, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 287256, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df4714000
mprotect(0x7f4df471e000, 237568, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4df471e000, 184320, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7f4df471e000
mmap(0x7f4df474b000, 49152, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x37000) = 0x7f4df474b000
mmap(0x7f4df4758000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x43000) = 0x7f4df4758000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=176800, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 181896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df46e7000
mprotect(0x7f4df46ed000, 143360, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4df46ed000, 110592, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f4df46ed000
mmap(0x7f4df4708000, 28672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x21000) = 0x7f4df4708000
mmap(0x7f4df4710000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x28000) = 0x7f4df4710000
mmap(0x7f4df4712000, 5768, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4df4712000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320v\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2224288, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 1953104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df450a000
mmap(0x7f4df4530000, 1400832, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x26000) = 0x7f4df4530000
mmap(0x7f4df4686000, 339968, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17c000) = 0x7f4df4686000
mmap(0x7f4df46d9000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ce000) = 0x7f4df46d9000
mmap(0x7f4df46df000, 32080, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4df46df000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libblkid.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=234736, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 230296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df44d1000
mprotect(0x7f4df44d9000, 172032, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4df44d9000, 131072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7f4df44d9000
mmap(0x7f4df44f9000, 36864, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x28000) = 0x7f4df44f9000
mmap(0x7f4df4503000, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x31000) = 0x7f4df4503000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=642072, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 639536, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df4434000
mprotect(0x7f4df4437000, 622592, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4df4437000, 442368, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7f4df4437000
mmap(0x7f4df44a3000, 176128, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6f000) = 0x7f4df44a3000
mmap(0x7f4df44cf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9a000) = 0x7f4df44cf000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4df4432000
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4df442f000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4df442f800) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f4df442fad0)         = 19946
set_robust_list(0x7f4df442fae0, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7f4df4430120, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4df46d9000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4df44cf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4df4503000, 24576, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4df4710000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4df4758000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55996ec48000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4df479b000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f4df475b000, 42399)           = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", {f_type=SYSFS_MAGIC, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=0, f_bfree=0, f_bavail=0, f_files=0, f_ffree=0, f_fsid={val=[0, 0]}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096, f_flags=ST_VALID|ST_NOSUID|ST_NODEV|ST_NOEXEC|ST_RELATIME}) = 0
statfs("/selinux", 0x7fff67a72f20)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getrandom("\x81\xcb\xaa\xff\x6a\x67\x91\x36", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55996f246000
brk(0x55996f267000)                     = 0x55996f267000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\ttmpfs\nnodev\tbd"..., 1024) = 447
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/mounts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "HMMMN7MO4YI:/var/lib/docker/over"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "S3KUUCPPARKVN:/var/lib/docker/ov"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "verlay2/l/5NHALYCMOAFB3RZRIZ2X6I"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "ADYTI:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "f814d803dee113/work 0 0\noverlay "..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "perdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "ce239/merged overlay rw,relatime"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "P2SJHP7H4T:/var/lib/docker/overl"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "lay2/l/CO2BS4PALMV3ML43Q7DXJJ5DO"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "RV:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/4N"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "/4b9321a40123e95f357129e30889341"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "lib/docker/overlay2/l/IOQE2QO7SA"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "KS37X535KNWHSIOKV:/var/lib/docke"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "er/overlay2/l/Q6U5F5AFXNU6J2RQDW"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "XSM2MWMUL:/var/lib/docker/overla"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "ay2/l/T5TTLHPXXTIZYXFJTYEKBM6HBB"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "Q:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/PJE"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "lay2/65ba63aac8a9c4bb0888f80b87b"..., 1024) = 1024
read(3, "6982 nsfs rw 0 0\ntmpfs /run/user"..., 1024) = 139
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2998, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2998
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_IDENTIFICATION", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=345, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 345, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df479a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27012, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 27012, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df475f000
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7f4df46dea6c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_MEASUREMENT", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=23, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 23, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df475e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_TELEPHONE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=52, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 52, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df475d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_ADDRESS", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=154, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 154, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df475c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_NAME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=62, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 62, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df475b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_PAPER", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=34, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 34, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df442e000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=29, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=57, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 57, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df442d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_MONETARY", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=294, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 294, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df442c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_COLLATE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2586930, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2586930, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df4000000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_TIME", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3196, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3196, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df442b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_NUMERIC", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=54, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 54, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df442a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/en_IE.utf8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=353616, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 353616, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4df43d3000
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
readlink("/dev", 0x7fff67a71760, 1023)  = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/dev/md127", 0x7fff67a71760, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/md127", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x9, 0x7f), ...}, 0) = 0
access("/dev/md127", F_OK)              = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/md127", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fadvise64(3, 0, 0, POSIX_FADV_RANDOM)   = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0x9, 0x7f), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKGETSIZE64, [80001806368768]) = 0
ioctl(3, FDGETFDCSTAT, 0x7fff67a6fad0)  = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/9:127", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(4, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/dev/block/9:127", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
faccessat2(4, "partition", F_OK, 0)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(4, "dm/uuid", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
ioctl(3, CDROM_GET_CAPABILITY, 0)       = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, CDROM_LAST_WRITTEN, 0x7fff67a6fa10) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(3, BLKGETZONESZ, [0])             = 0
lseek(3, 80001806303232, SEEK_SET)      = 80001806303232
read(3,
```

At `read(3,` it just hangs.

Comment: Let the rebuild finish, then replace the failing disk, rebuild again, then fsck the filesystem????

Comment: It's worrying that I can run `mdadm --examine` against each of the disks, but not the raid device. I can run almost no useful tools against the raid device to better understand the state it's in, they all just hang in a waiting state.

Comment: I'm not an expert with RAID6 (I've used RAID1 a fair bit), but I wonder if a significant part of your problem is the load the rebuild is putting on the disks.   I know that way-back-when, when disks started swapping or otherwise had high disk IO, systems became very (disconcertingly) unresponsive.  Your rebuild is taking place at 88 megabytes per second - which seems to my untrained mind to be quite fast for spinning disks....

Comment: Can you slow the rebuild to a crawl (eg use sysctl to change dev.raid.speed_limit_max to close to 0, wait for the disks to settle, do your tests, then increase the build speed)?  I do comment that best practice when doing data recovery - and this is akin to that - is reduce the amount of activity seen by the failing disk as much as possible - so waiting it out could provide the best long term outcome.

Comment: I just froze the resync `echo frozen > /sys/block/md127/md/sync_action` and can see the io dropped to zero, but almost all commands against the drive continue to hang.

Comment: Thanks for your edit here, @JonathanCremin. In a similar situation and not a lot of docs on this. I added 2 drives to an array and it blocked when reshaping started. I guess live reshaping only works with 1 drive. I'll let it finish, as you did.